# $_POST for submit input don't work via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Maybe I am so blind and solution is simple but I really don't know where is problem. Problem is that, input type text output ok, file too, but input type submit is still empty.

**This is my html:**

```
<form class="Popup_form" method="post">
            <div class="vyskakuj_popup">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" name="pribeh2" value="Pridať">
                <textarea placeholder="Text..." name="ZO_text_input"></textarea>
            </div> <!-- koniec "vyskakuj_popup" -->
        </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
    $text = $_POST['ZO_text_input'];
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    echo $text; //OK
    echo $_POST['pribeh2']; //Undefined index: pribeh2, when var_dump output is NULL
    echo $name; // OK
?>
```

**And AJAX:**

```
$('.Popup_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../PHP/scripty_zvieratkoOnline.php',
        type: 'POST',            
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Input type submit is a button. If you need to pass some extra data create a hidden input.

Comment: I just need give this input into if(isset($_POST['pribeh2'])) but, it don't work becouse $_POST['pribeh2'] is not "isset" and is empty

Comment: As I said, input of the type submit is a button. https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_type.asp | If you need to pass a variable pribeh2 what you have to use is a hidden input

Comment: I will try it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: try adding `<form class="Popup_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">` in your form